# Shopware Slim Application Error after install

Tags: php, mysql, docker, curl, shopware

I am trying to install Shopware 6 (6.2.0_1589874223) into a Docker (Ubuntu 20.04) container. Everything works nicely, all the PHP modules are working and the MySQL database works as well.

Then comes the setup of Shopware over the web access page. The setup works nicely, but at the end the browser (Chrome) runs into the following error.

[image]

Is this an SSL error? Some kind of verification that fails? If yes, how can I turn that off in the Docker container? What problem does Curl exactly have?

Comment: "connection refused" means there's no app running on that URL. If you're running the app on `127.0.0.1` (localhost) in the container, try running it on `0.0.0.0` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shop cannot request itself with CURL. You can ignore it and just open the admin using /admin